# React: updating a state resets another state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing my first real React app and I ran into a bug I can't seem to fix.
I have a card component somewhere in my app that, when it gets clicked it maximizes to take up a bigger section of the screen. It is called in `MainSelectionButton.js` as follows:

```js
export default function MainSelectionButtons(props) {
  const [maximizeCard, setMaximizeCard] = useState('nothing')

  if (maximizeCard === 'nothing') {
    return <ImageButton
      title={props.title}
      icon={props.icon}
      whatIsMaximized={setMaximizeCard}
    />
  }
  else return <MaximizedPlot
    title={maximizeCard}
    whatIsMaximized={setMaximizeCard}
    cryptoData={props.cryptoData}
    daysChangeHandler={props.daysChangeHandler}
    days={props.days}
  />

}
```

`MaximizedPlot` looks like this:

```
export default function MaximizedPlot(props) {
  const sorter = (item) => {
    switch (item) {
      case 'Strategy Plot':
        return strategyPlot;
      case 'Value Plot':
        return valuePlot
      case 'Relative Plot':
        return relativePlot;
      default: break
    }
  }
  const daysChangeHandler = (newDays) => {
    props.daysChangeHandler(newDays)
  }
  const xButtonHandler = () => {
    props.whatIsMaximized('nothing')
  }
  const title = (props.days === 0) ? 'the maximal number of days' : props.days
  return <Card backgroundColor='#192734' isMaximized='maximized' >
    <XButton onClick={() => xButtonHandler()}>x</XButton>
    <h1>{props.title + ' over ' + title}</h1>
    <img src={sorter(props.title)} width='100%' alt=''></img>
    <NumberOfDays daysChangeHandler={daysChangeHandler}
      cryptoData={props.cryptoData}>
    </NumberOfDays>
  </Card>
}
```

This component looks like this:
[Maximized card component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT4mw.png)

With the `XButton` component on the top right corner and the `NumberOfDays` component being the input field at the bottom of the graph.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [cryptoData, setCryptoData] = useState({ timestamp: [], price: [], long_ma: [], short_ma: [], money: [], action: [] })
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(744)
  useEffect(() => {
    getData(30 * 24).then(response => setCryptoData(response))
  }, []);
  const daysChangeHandler = (days) => {
    setHours(days * 24, getData(hours).then(response => setCryptoData(response)))
    console.log('days Changed!! new:', days)
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card isMaximized=''>
        <MainSelectionButtons title={'Strategy Plot'} icon={iconStrategy} cryptoData={cryptoData} daysChangeHandler={daysChangeHandler} days={hours / 24}></MainSelectionButtons>
        <MainSelectionButtons title={'Value Plot'} icon={iconValue} cryptoData={cryptoData} daysChangeHandler={daysChangeHandler} days={hours / 24}></MainSelectionButtons>
        <MainSelectionButtons title={'Relative Plot'} icon={iconRelative} cryptoData={cryptoData} daysChangeHandler={daysChangeHandler} days={hours / 24}></MainSelectionButtons>
      </Card>
      <Card>
        is running
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

EDIT: the user input component, called `NumberOfDays` looks like this:

```
export default function NumberOfDays(props) {
    const [typedDays, setTypedDays] = useState(30)
    const inputDaysChangeHandler = (event) => {
        setTypedDays(event.target.value)
    }
    const submitHandler = () => {
        props.daysChangeHandler(typedDays)
    }
    const predefinedDaysHandler = (days) => {
        props.daysChangeHandler(days)
    }
    return <div>
        <div className='input-form'>
            Enter number of days to display: &nbsp;
            <input type='number'
                onChange={inputDaysChangeHandler}
                className='days-number-input' />
            <input
                type='submit'
                className='submit-button'
                onClick={() => submitHandler()} />
            &nbsp; or:&nbsp;
            <button className='submit-button' onClick={() => predefinedDaysHandler(0)}>Max</button>
            <button className='submit-button' onClick={() => predefinedDaysHandler(30)}>30 days</button>
            <button className='submit-button' onClick={() => predefinedDaysHandler(240)} >10 days</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

## THE PROBLEM

Whenever I click on a button in the user input field (so 'submit', 'max', etc.) the window gets minimized. I can't figure out why, it just closes every time. What am I doing wrong? Is there something fundamentally wrong with my code or is it a little logical mistake that I am missing?

Thank you in advance for the help, I spent already more time on it than I'd like to admit.

## UPDATE:

If anyone has this problem, It is solved if instead of using props, you use context.

Comment: not able to understand the problem!. where is this "user input field (so 'submit', 'max', etc.)"?

Comment: @sojin, thank you for pointing out that it was unclear, I added it to the post!

Comment: Check whether the Xbutton is overlapping other sections in HTML, might be CSS issue. also try to add `e.preventDefault()`, and `e.stopPropagation()` to stop the click event

Comment: So the html elements are arranged as follows: <div>
<XButton/>
<div USERINPUT HERE>
</div>
</div>. As for the preventDefault and stopPropagation, where? on the submit button it seems to do nothing differently.